# C# view - font color

Tags: c#, sql, razor, view

I have a view that's displaying data from a database/table. If the field is a certain value, i want that instance to display as having red text. I have tried this, unfortunately I think the foreach loop (which I need) is causing issues. Specifically, it's making all the text red, not just the instances I want.

```
 <tbody>
          @foreach (var item in Model)
    {      
        var T2stat = @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.T2STATUS).ToString();
        var T3stat = @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.T3STATUS).ToString();     
        <tr>                                               
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EXPORT_DATE)
        </td>
            @if ((T2stat != "") && (T2stat != "Exported")) {
                <td><p style="color:red">
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.T2STATUS)
        </p></td>
            }
            else{
                <td><p style="color:black">
              @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.T2STATUS)
                    </p></td>  
            }                               
         @if ((T3stat != "") && (T3stat != "Exported")) {
                <td><p style="color:red">
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.T3STATUS)
        </p></td>
            }
            else{
                <td><p style="color:black">
              @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.T3STATUS)
                   </p></td>  
            }
```

I changed the variable definitions to....

```
 var T2stat = (item.T2STATUS != null) ? item.T2STATUS.ToString() : String.Empty;
 var T3stat = (item.T3STATUS != null) ? item.T3STATUS.ToString() : String.Empty;
```

Unfortunately, I still have the same issue, where values are appearing red despite me assigning black as the text color. I.e; "Exported" should always appear as black text,null also black, but it's red which should be only for error message.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is in these assignments:

```
var T2stat = @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.T2STATUS).ToString();
var T3stat = @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.T3STATUS).ToString();
```

This will assign these variables the rendered value of the display template, not the data value.

Perhaps you meant this?

```
var T2stat = (item.T2STATUS != null) ? item.T2STATUS.ToString() : String.Empty;
var T3stat = (item.T3STATUS != null) ? item.T3STATUS.ToString() : String.Empty;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this....

```
<tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {   
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EXPORT_DATE)
            </td>

            <td>
                <p  @((item.T2STATUS == null) || (item.T2STATUS == "Exported") ? "style=\"color:black;\"" : "style=\"color:red;\"")>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.T2STATUS)
                </p>
            </td>

            <td>
                <p @((item.T3STATUS == null) || (item.T3STATUS == "Exported") ? "style=\"color:black;\"" : "style=\"color:red;\"")>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.T3STATUS)
                </p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```

Do let me know if you need anything else...or this dosen't works.. :)

Comment: All text is black now having implemented your solution. hmm.

Comment: Check the condition i wrote....is it matches your criteria...I wrote && condition...

Comment: There are 3 possible entries. Exported (black), null, or an error message (red) Export Failed: File "C:\BillingExport\BILLING_TABLE_FILE02.txt" has not been imported. I want the text black on everything except the error message entries.

Comment: so you can edit the condition as per what u want as o/p...do edit ques with the entries...

Comment: or did not fix the problem, it should be and. the part it's getting tripped up on is ? "style=\"color:red;\"" : "style=\"color:black;\"").

Comment: I changed the code....black first and then red...I think u missed it... check it..

Comment: all text is still black. It's not making the text red when the field value is neither "" nor "Exported".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58642/discussion-between-x-developer-and-dave).